# Why am I getting a 403 Forbidden error when trying to access authenticated routes in React frontend, even though login is successful?

Tags: reactjs, api, authentication, passport.js, passport-local

**Api is not able to detect login **
It works on postman but not working in frontend which I made using react .

This is my authentication controller login part.

```
const login = async (req, res) => {
  passport.authenticate("local", (err, user, info) => {
    if (err) {
      return res.status(500).json({ message: "Internal Server Error" });
    }
    if (!user) {
      return res.status(401).json({ message: info.message });
    }
    req.logIn(user, (err) => {
      if (err) {
        return res.status(500).json({ message: "Internal Server Error" });
      }
      return res.json({ message: "Login successful", user: req.user });
    });
  })(req, res);
};
```

This is my songs controller recommendation function .

```
const recommendation = async (req, res) => {
  try {
    const recommend = req.user.recommendation;
    if (recommend != null) {
      Song.find({ category: recommend }, (err, foundSongs) => {
        res.json({ foundSongs });
      });
    } else {
      Song.find((err, foundSongs) => {
        res.json({ foundSongs });
      });
    }
  } catch (err) {
    console.log(err);
  }
};
```

And this is my isAuthenticated middleware .

```
const isAuthenticated = (req, res, next) => {
  if (req.isAuthenticated()) {
    next();
  } else {
    res.status(403).json({ message: "You need to login first." });
  }
};

module.exports = isAuthenticated;
```

This is my login route `app.post("/login", login);` and this is my /recommendedsongs route `app.get("/recommendedsongs", isAuthenticated, recommendation);`

When I try to use POSTMAN all the routes and functionalities work fine . When I login using POSTMAN I am able to send requests to multiple routes where authentication is required by logging in only once .

Whereas this is my forntend for this api using react

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from "react";
import axios from "axios";

const API_BASE_URL = "http://localhost:5000";

function App() {
  const [username, setUsername] = useState("");
  const [password, setPassword] = useState("");
  const [isLoggedIn, setIsLoggedIn] = useState(false);
  const [user, setUser] = useState(null);
  const [recommendedSongs, setRecommendedSongs] = useState([]);

  useEffect(() => {
    checkLoginStatus();
  }, []);

  const login = async (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    try {
      const response = await axios.post(`${API_BASE_URL}/login`, {
        email: username,
        password,
      });
      console.log(response.data);
      checkLoginStatus();
    } catch (error) {
      console.error(error);
    }
  };

  const logout = async (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    try {
      const response = await axios.post(`${API_BASE_URL}/logout`);
      console.log(response.data);
      checkLoginStatus();
    } catch (error) {
      console.error(error);
    }
  };

  const checkLoginStatus = async () => {
    try {
      const response = await axios.get(`${API_BASE_URL}/checkloginstatus`);
      const { isLoggedIn, user } = response.data;
      setIsLoggedIn(isLoggedIn);
      setUser(user);
    } catch (error) {
      console.error(error);
    }
  };

  const getRecommendedSongs = async () => {
    try {
      const response = await axios.get(`${API_BASE_URL}/recommendedsongs`);
      setRecommendedSongs(response.data);
    } catch (error) {
      console.error(error);
    }
  };

  return (
    <div>
      <h1>API Frontend Example</h1>
      {!isLoggedIn ? (
        <form>
          <h2>Login</h2>
          <input
            type="text"
            placeholder="Username"
            value={username}
            onChange={(e) => setUsername(e.target.value)}
          />
          <input
            type="password"
            placeholder="Password"
            value={password}
            onChange={(e) => setPassword(e.target.value)}
          />
          <button type="submit" onClick={login}>
            Login
          </button>
        </form>
      ) : (
        <div>
          <h2>Welcome, {user && user.email}</h2>
          <button type="submit" onClick={logout}>
            Logout
          </button>
        </div>
      )}

      <button type="submit" onClick={getRecommendedSongs}>
        Get Recommended Songs
      </button>

      {recommendedSongs.length > 0 && (
        <div>
          <h3>Recommended Songs:</h3>
          <ul>
            {recommendedSongs.map((song) => (
              <li key={song.id}>{song.title}</li>
            ))}
          </ul>
        </div>
      )}
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

when I login i am getting the message that login is successful but after loggin in when I click the "Get Recommended Songs" button it says 403 forbidden . Which should not happend as I am already logged in. I don't know why this is not working . When I use POSTMAN everything is working well but in the frontend this error occurs . Is the error in my api or the frontend ?